# Unable to figure operation of my github status check operation

Tags: git, github, git-push, github-actions, github-codereviews

This is my protected branch (master) configuration:

[image]

And this is what I tried:

```
$ git push
Enumerating objects: 5, done.
Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 306 bytes | 306.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (1/1), completed with 1 local object.
remote: error: GH006: Protected branch update failed for refs/heads/master.
remote: error: Required status check "build-pipeline" is expected.
To github.com:AdityaGovardhan/my-repo.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (protected branch hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:AdityaGovardhan/my-repo.git'
```

So I have a github `my-repo` repository. I have a `build-pipeline` GitHub Action which I have kept as required for a commit to be added to master. Here's what the required checks statement says:

> Choose which status checks must pass before branches can be merged into a branch that matches this rule. When enabled, commits must first be pushed to another branch, then merged or ***pushed directly to a branch that matches this rule after status checks have passed.***

So here's what I expected would happen. I can push from my local master to remote master (which is protected) directly because of ***that last statement^***, but the commit will be in an intermediate state at remote because `build-pipeline` status check have not been successful yet. I am aware that that's not how git works. But then what's the point of ***that last statement^*** when it is forcing me to create a non-protected branch and raise a pull request to perform `build-pipeline` status check and then merge to master.

Comment: "this is what I tried: `git push`". But `git push` _what?_ What branch were you on when you said this? You cannot push _directly_ to the protected branch; it says that, right in the instructions you quoted. You have to push to _another_ branch and then merge.

Comment: @matt Sorry to assume that the git command output would be sufficient to understand the context. Yes, I pushed from master branch to remote master branch. Creating another branch and merging is surely one of the ways but I am more curious about the later bolded statement. "branch that matches this rule" means protected branch. It does allow pushing directly to protected branch but I don't know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On GitHub, status checks are applied to a commit.  While the typical workflow is to open a PR and merge changes that way, it may be possible to push your changes to a different branch, let the status checks run there, and then fast-forward your `master` branch to that version.  The commit would already have passed the checks.

Note that I have not tested this, and again, it's not the usual workflow, it may be something you can try.  It would be a potential workflow option for people who do rebases and prefer a linear history.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So "pushed directly to a branch that matches this rule" means rebasing off a different remote branch?

Comment: The phrase “pushed directly to a branch that matches this rule” means in your case the `master` branch.  I'm proposing you push your local `master` to another branch, let the status checks run, and then push that same commit to the remote `master` when it passes.

Comment: I understand what you mean by  "status checks are applied to a commit" now. I pushed the commit to non-protected branch, got it 'status-checked' and then pushed it again to the protected branch and it's working fine. The phrase “pushed directly to a branch that matches this rule” sounded confusing. This is a good way to circumvent superfluous pull requests (and corresponding notifications) which are not meant for review.